# How to reset specific MongoDB collections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to learn how to develop using a MEAN stack and was following along a tutorial provided by IBM on how to implement a polling app using Node and Mongoose. I was wondering if there is any concise way to reset certain variables within a collection through Javascript? My structure looks like this:

[image]

How would I go about resetting "votes" to an empty array?

Comment: I'm unsure which documents you'd want to reset, but I think you could query for those documents & then use [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) to set votes to be empty.

Comment: @elefont thanks for the suggestion, I tried using this route earlier and it did not seem to work out for me. Specifically what I tried was:

    db.polls.update( { _v: 1 }, { $set: { "votes": [] } } )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.polls.update( { __v: 1 }, { $set: { "choices.$.votes": [] } } )
```